# Optimal measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, optimization, expected-value

I am studying conditional expectations and I have a doubt that if it is possible to maximise over a family of measures. It means, let $X$ be a random variable, $A$ be a set and $\mathcal{P}$ be a family of probability measures is it possible  to compute
\begin{equation}
Y=\sup_{\mathbb{P}\in \mathcal{P}} \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[X|A\right]
\end{equation}
I mean, for instance to compute the maximum of a function $f$ we can compute the first derivative $f'$. Does it exist a similar way to find Y?. Maybe in the case when each $\mathbb{P}$ has density function $f_\mathbb{P}$ is it possible to obtain using something like
\begin{equation}
\frac{d Y}{df_\mathbb{P}}
\end{equation}
I would like to know if there exist some similar result or theory about it. Any help or advice is welcome. Thank you!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that $\ \mathcal{P}\ $  is the set of *all* probability measures on some $\ \sigma$-algebra $\ \mathscr{A}\ $ for which $\ A\in\mathscr{A}\ $ and with respect to which $\ X\ $ is a random variable (i.e. measurable). I made this assumption because I initially misread the description of  $\ \mathcal{P}\ $ as being *the* family of probability measures rather than *a* family of probability measures. I don't believe the question is answerable for an *arbitrary* family of probability measures about which no further information is available.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
If $\ a\in A\ $ and
$$
\mathbb{P}_a(B)\ed\cases{1&if $\ X(a)\in B$\\
0&if $\ X(a)\not\in B$}\ ,
$$
then
$$
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}_a}(X\,|\,A\,)=X(a)\ ,
$$
and since $\ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}(X\,|\,A\,)\le\sup_\limits{a\in A}X(a)\ $ for any probability measure $\ \mathbb{P}\ ,$ it follows from this that
$$
\sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}(X\,|\,A\,)=\sup_{a\in A}X(a)\ .\label{e1}\tag{1}
$$
Also, $\ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}(X\,|\,A\,)\ $ attains the supremum in (\ref{e1}) at some $\ \mathbb{P}^*\in\mathcal{P}\ $ if and only if $\ X(a)\ $ attains it at some $\ a^*\in A\ .$

If $\ a^*\in A\ $ satisfies
$$
X\big(a^*\big)=\sup_{a\in A}X(a)
$$
then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}_{a^*}}(X\,|\,A\,)&=X\big(a^*\big)\\
&=\sup_{a\in A}X(a)\\
&=\sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}(X\,|\,A\,)\ .
\end{align}
On the other hand, if $\ X(a)<\sup_\limits{a\in A}X(a)\ $ for all $\ a\in A\ ,$ and $\ \mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}\ ,$ then
$$
A=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty\left\{a\in A\,\left|\,X(a)\le\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{1}{j}\,\right.\right\}\ .
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
1&=\mathbb{P}(A\,|\,A\,)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty\left\{a\in A\,\left|\,X(a)\le\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{1}{j}\,\right\}\right|A\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n\left\{a\in A\,\left|\,X(a)\le\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{1}{j}\,\right\}\right|A\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{a\in A\,\left|\,X(a)\le\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{1}{n}\,\right\}\right|A\right)\ ,
\end{align}
from which it follow that there exist a positive integer $\ N\ $ such that
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{p}&\ed\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{a\in A\,\left|\,X(a)\le\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{1}{N}\,\right\}\right|A\right)\\
&\ge\frac{1}{2}\ .
\end{align}
Let
$$
B\ed\left\{a\in A\,\left|\,X(a)\le\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{1}{N}\,\right\}\right.\ .
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}(X\,|\,A\,)&=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\big(I_BX+I_{A\setminus B}X\,\big|\,A\,\big)\\
&=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\big(I_BX\,\big|\,A\,\big)+\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\big(I_{A\setminus B}X\,\big|\,A\,\big)\\
&\le\mathfrak{p}\left(\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{1}{N}\right)+(1-\mathfrak{p})\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)\\
&=\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)-\frac{\mathfrak{p}}{N}\\
&<\sup_\limits{\alpha\in A}X(\alpha)\ .
\end{align}
Thus, if $\ X(a)\ $ doesn't attain the supremum in (\ref{e1}) for any $\ a\in A\ ,$ then neither does
$\ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}(X\,|\,A\,)\ $ attain it for any $\ \mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}\ .$